# How to make this work for 3 users and pass instead of 1 C

Tags: c

**So I have 2 txt files. one is password other is login. I figured out how to make it work for 1 login and 1 pass. How do I make it work for 3 logins in one txt compared to 3 passwords of pass txt. In C **

```
int main()
{
FILE*p1;
int login;
char buf1[15];
char buf2[15];
p1=fopen("login.txt","rt");
fgets(buf1,15,p1);
login=strcmp(buf1,p1);
fclose(p1);
FILE*p2;
int password;
p2=fopen("password.txt","rt");
password=strcmp(buf2,p2);
fgets(buf2,15,p2);
fclose(p2);
printf("Login: ");
scanf("%s", p1);
printf("Password: ");
scanf("%s", p2);

if(strcmp(buf1, p1))

    if(strcmp(buf2, p2))
    {
        printf("\nIncorrect!\n");
    }
    else

        printf("\nWelcome!\n");

}
```

Comment: If nothing else, you don't do `strcmp(buf1, p1)`, where `p1` is a `FILE *`.  That's completely meaningless (and your compiler should have warned you about it).  Don't do `scanf("%s", p1)`, either -- equally meaningless.

Comment: After you call `fopen`, `p1` and `p2` are variables describing the file, variables you can use to read stuff out of the file, but they do *not* simply contain what the files contain.  After you read strings out of the file, using calls like `fgets(buf1,15,p1)` and `fgets(buf2,15,p2)`, then you've got strings `buf1` and `buf2`, and those are strings you can do comparisons on.

Comment: You have two `char` buffers to hold strings, but I think you're going to need four: (1) the username you've read from the user, (2) the password you've read from the user, (3) one of the usernames you've read from `login.txt`, (4) one of the passwords you've read from `password.txt`.

Comment: yes I understand its not a good code, but it works.I just need it to work with 3 Logins in one .txt file and 3 passwords in the other .txt file.

Comment: Actually, no, it doesn't work.  If it seems to work, it's by a rather incredible accident.  And before you can get it to work for two or more entries in the files, you're simply going to have to fix the other problems.  (I might be able to give you some more hints later, but now I have to go.)

Comment: So what should I use instead of scanf?   I made the bufs and got rid of the strcmp

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare *four* string buffers you'll need: `char username[50], password[50], tryuser[50], trypass[50];`.
2. Get rid of the `login=strcmp(buf1, p1)` and `password=strcmp(buf2, p2)` calls. Those are meaningless and don't do anything.  (Among other things you haven't even read the user's input to compare to yet.)
3. Prompt the user for their username and password, reading them in to `username` and `password`.  (You can continue to use `scanf` for this.)
4. Open the two files for reading.
5. Enter a loop.  Each time through the loop, read one username from `login.txt` into `tryuser` and one password from `password.txt` into `trypass`.  Stop (break out of) the loop when either read fails.  You can continue to use `fgets` for this, or you could use `fscanf` here, too. (I wouldn't use it myself, but you might find it advantageous.)  I'll have a bit more to say about this loop below.
6. If you used `fgets` to read the `tryuser` and `trypass`, they contain a newline (`'\n'`) character.  This will interfere with string matching.  Eliminate this newline, perhaps by calling `strtok(tryuser, "\n")` (and the same for `trypass`).
7. Compare `username` to `tryuser` and `password` to `trypass`, using something like the two `if` statements you already had.  Your `strcmp` calls were inverted, though -- to test if `username` matches `tryuser`, you want `if(strcmp(username, tryuser) == 0)`.
8. Arrange that, if the username matches, you break out of the loop, regardless of whether the password matched.  But if the username did not match, continue to the next trip through the loop.  (You're still looking for a matching username.)

It's a little bit tricky to have a loop that's doing two things at once -- in this case, reading one username from `p1` and one password from `p2` -- and that stops when either thing fails.  One way to write it would be

```
while(fgets(tryuser, 50, p1) != NULL && fgets(trypass, 50, p2) != NULL)
```